# asp.net DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, web, drop-down-menu, load, refresh

Currently I have a drop downlist as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" 

    OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectionHasChanged"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" 
                 Width="214px">
            /asp:DropDownList>

            asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDBConnectionString1 %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], Name], [Name] FROM [Names]">
            /asp:SqlDataSource>
```

There are two things I'm trying to get the list to do when selection is either updated or deleted:
1)Remove deleted contents from `DropDownList` 
2)The first entry in the database is found in the field when the page is loaded, I would like it to either be blank or say "Select"

Currently I need to refress the page to refresh the dropdownlist of deleted items.

I have tried adding `DropDownList1.DataBind();` in various methods (page_load, update, delete) and `DropDownList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;` (but I get a message to delete an object of (SqlDataSource1?)

I have added a tag/controll called `EnableViewState="false"`, this refreshs the dropdownlist when I select another item, but when I delete an item I need the list to refresh right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In order to delete an item from your dropdown list, what you do is to loop through the `ListItem` of dropdown list compare the value field (`DataValueField`) of `ListItem` item with the selection that has changed or deleted, remove it from dropdown list if it matches. e.g.:

```
private void removeItem(string ID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dropdownList.Items.Count; i++)
            if (dropdownList.Items[i].Value == ID)
            {
                dropdownList.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
    }
```

2.Just after binding your dropdownlist, in code behind, add a new `ListItem` at `Index` 0, it will solve your problem of displaying "Select" or Blank as a top most selection:

```
dropdownList.DataBind();
dropdownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciated it. Just to make sure I'm doing this correct I add the private void removeItem into my code behind file, and the dropdownlist.bind and . items.insert into my update and delete methods? Also, my ID is an int in the database how would I convert the string. When adding covert.int32(ID) it doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: you don't need to call dropdownlist.Bind when you are deleting an item from dropdownlist.. and in order to converting an integer to string you could use .toString() method